# Execute code on different subsets

Tags: r, subset, repeat, lapply

I have a data.frame with couple of thousands rows. I am applying several lines of code to subsets of this data.

I have 4 subsets in a column "*mergeorder$phylum*":

```
[1] "ascomycota"      "basidiomycota"   "unidentified"   
[4] "chytridiomycota"
```

And on every subset i have to apply this set of functions separately:

```
ascomycota<-mergeorder[mergeorder$phylum %in% c("ascomycota"), ]
group_ascomycota <- aggregate(ascomycota[,2:62], by=list(ascomycota$order), FUN=sum)

row.names(group_ascomycota)<-group_ascomycota[,1]
group_ascomycota$sum <-apply(group_ascomycota[,-1],1,sum) 

dat5 <-sweep(group_ascomycota[,2:62], 2, colSums(group_ascomycota[2:62]), '/')
dat5$sum <-apply(group_ascomycota[,-1],1,sum)
reorder_dat5 <- dat5[order(dat5$sum, decreasing=T),]

reorder_dat5$OTU_ID <- row.names(reorder_dat5)
FINITO<-reorder_dat5[1:15,]

write.table(FINITO, file="output_ITS1/ITS1_ascomycota_order_top15.csv", col.names=TRUE,row.names=FALSE, sep=",", quote=FALSE)
```

This code works. However, I would like to apply this code without manually replacing every "ascomycota" with "basidiomycota", "unidentified", "chytridiomycota".

What function should I use? How should I use it? I've been struggling with `sapply()`, `repeat()` but haven't come far.

The end result should execute the whole code and export csv separate files.

Many thanks for your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's usually possible to write code that handles all subsets in one go. However, what you are doing is pretty complicated. The best thing to do might be to gather all that into a function and then just run the function for each subset. Something like this:

```
subset_transform <- function(subset){
  t <-mergeorder[mergeorder$phylum %in% c(subset), ]
  group_t <- aggregate(t[,2:62], by=list(t$order), FUN=sum)

  row.names(group_t)<-group_t[,1]
  group_t$sum <-apply(group_t[,-1],1,sum) 

  dat5 <-sweep(group_t[,2:62], 2, colSums(group_t[2:62]), '/')
  dat5$sum <-apply(group_t[,-1],1,sum)
  reorder_dat5 <- dat5[order(dat5$sum, decreasing=T),]

  reorder_dat5$OTU_ID <- row.names(reorder_dat5)
  FINITO<-reorder_dat5[1:15,]

  write.table(FINITO, file = paste("output_ITS1/ITS1_", subset, "_order_top15.csv"), col.names=TRUE,row.names=FALSE, sep=",", quote=FALSE)
}

subset_transform("ascomycota")
subset_transform("basidiomycota")
subset_transform("unidentified")
subset_transform("chytridiomycota")
```

Comment: Rather than putting the subsetting code inside the function, it's pretty common to write a function that assumes the subsetting has been done, which can then work well with `dplyr::do` or `data.table` or even `base::split` and `lapply`.

Comment: @Gregor That would be a nice idea, thanks :)  I tried rewriting it like that, but it ended up being a bit awkward to name the table that was being written (as far as I could manage anyway). I'll keep it in mind for next time though.